# Does the diseased affect an alpha wolf?

Tags: werewolv.es

If the wolfpack kill the diseased, is the alpha wolf still able to enrage the following night?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, an Alphawolf would still be able to use their enrage ability.

UPDATE:

This has recently been changed - the Alphawolf can no longer enrage the night after the wolfpack eat a Diseased player. The Omegawolf is still unaffected.